# Spring security 401 Unauthorised despite of permitAll

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to do my second app using Spring Boot. I have problems with security config even if I use `permittAll` method. Here's part of my code with `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/users").authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }



    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

}
```

When I use Postman on /register I have 401 Unauthorised, tried to do it many ways but have no idea what to do anymore. Of course, Rest controller handles /register and /users.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you testing using this url: ADDRESS/register?

Comment: Yest I', testing using localhost:8080/register.